# Load content from MySQL on scroll with AJAX post

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I have a segment of my website which needs to dynamically load content when the user reaches the bottom. I'm using jQuery, and this is the code to detect the scroll:

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
    $(window).scroll(function() {
        if($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() == $(document).height()) {
        alert("Bottom reached");
            $('div#loadMoreComments').show();
            dataStr = "from=" + $(".n:last").attr('id')
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "ajax/query.php",
                data: dataStr,
                success: function(html) {
                    if(html){       
                        $("#hold").append(html);
                        alert("Data was added");
                    }
                    else{       
                        $('div#loadMoreComments').replaceWith("<center><h1 style='color:red'>End of countries !!!!!!!</h1></center>");
                        alert("Data was not added");
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    });
});
```

The first problem I have is that the scroll to the bottom is only detected when the user reaches the top of the page. The second problem is that it doesn't load any content, at all, because the variable doesn't seem to be posted, here's my code in the query.php:

```
if(array_key_exists('from', $_POST)) {
    $from = htmlspecialchars(stripslashes(mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['from'])));
    $to = 15;
    $re = ("SELECT status as status, sid as sid, UNIX_TIMESTAMP(timestamp) as timestamp FROM mingle_status WHERE uid = '$uid' ORDER BY timestamp DESC LIMIT $from,$to"); //query
  }
  else {
    $re = ("SELECT id as id, status as status, sid as sid, UNIX_TIMESTAMP(timestamp) as timestamp FROM mingle_status WHERE uid = '$uid' ORDER BY timestamp DESC LIMIT 1"); //query
  }
  $result = mysql_query($re) or die (mysql_error());
  while($st = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $status = nl2br($st['status']);
    $sid = $st['sid'];  
    $td = $st['timestamp'];
    $id = $st['id'];
    ?>
        <div id="<?php echo $id; ?>" class="id">
            <!-- stuff -->
        </div>
    <?php
    }
    ?>
```

And the error:

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '",15' at line 1
```

If anyone could help me with this, it'd be great, I'd really appreciate it.

**EDIT:** Okay, I can now get a div generated, but only when I scroll to the top of the page, and it only appends one div, and if I scroll to the top again, it appends the exact same div.

Comment: does the dataStr get created properly? what happens when you add print_r($_POST) to the php to what is being posted to query.php?

Comment: is the $from a string or number - looks like an inverted comma is being added to the sql screwing up the limit

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is just wrong:

```
$from = htmlspecialchars(stripslashes(mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['from'])));
```

If `from` is supposed to be an integer, just use:

```
$from = (int) $_POST['from'];
```

I also see that that number comes from an id in the html and ids cannot start with a number.

**Edit:** An additional problem is that you are not selecting the ID in your sql query if `from` exists and even if you would do that, this approach can lead to problems in the future when you delete records and your IDs are not sequential any more.

About the first problem, I can solve that in firebug changing:

```
 if($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() == $(document).height()) {
```

to:

```
 if( ($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height()) > ($(document).height() -  10) ) {
```

**Edit 2:** To solve your non-sequential ID problem, the easiest way would be to calculate `from` in javascript using something like:

```
dataStr = "from=" + $(".n").length;    // just count the number of elements you are showing already
```

Comment: That fixed my second problem, but it's created two new ones, 1) it's only adding one div to the bottom of #hold, 2) when I scroll again, it appends the same div...

Comment: @AviateX14 What does the generated html look like?

Comment: As it should, all the id's being put in the right places, however the id for .n is the first entry in the database, where as it should be 92 (the one above it before scroll was 93)

Comment: It fires the ajax constantly now

Comment: @AviateX14 Just use something like firebug and play with the values to see what works best for you.

Comment: Okay, thanks a lot. Last thing, what can I do to make the query select the next 15 rows from the last id?

Comment: @AviateX14 I already put that in my edit, you need to select the ID also when a `from` post value exists, just add `id as id,` like in the second query.

Comment: @AviateX14 One last edit to get rid of the dependence on the ID from the database for your `from` value...

Comment: I still have a problem, it's still only outputting one record, and then when I reach the bottom again, it outputs the exact same record as before

Comment: @AviateX14 You will need to put your actual code and html in the question, it's hard to see what you have now.