# Dynamic loading elements from database

Tags: php, mysql, database, dynamic, comments

I'm trying to create a blog thing which displays comments stored inside a database: however I would like the comments to appear when the user scrolls down, dynamically creating it on the page, rather than having links to the next set of comments.

At the moment I am using MySQL with php to display the comments stored.

```
$query  = "SELECT * FROM comment ORDER BY time DESC";
$result = mysql_query($query);

while($data = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
  echo "<comment><div class='comment-bubble'><p>" . $data['comment'] . "</p></div>";
  //other div structure & data here
}
```

I know there are plugins available like [jscroll](http://jscroll.com/). But this fetches data from other HTML files rather than from a database.

I know the method may need changing as php loads the data before the page is ... so what would be the best way to go about this?

Thanks guys!

Comment: You should consider using "limit" combination in mysql query as when you scroll.

Comment: I think you need to visit this [page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11212396/load-content-from-mysql-on-scroll-with-ajax-post)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so from the amount of research I put into this: it is actually impossible to update dynamically through mySQL without loading all the comments first. This is because PhP loads before the page displays it, so JavaScript cannot dynamically present more comments *unless* the page is refreshed.

I am going to give a whirl at AJAX as it is made for dynamically changing websites. I hopefully will post my full answer to the problem soon.

**EDIT:** Using jquery AJAX I came up with this:

```
//Load more comments when reaching the end of the page
var isPreviousEventComplete = true, isDataAvailable = true;
$(window).scroll(function () {
    if ($(document).height() - 50 <= $(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height()) {
        if (isPreviousEventComplete && isDataAvailable) {

            isPreviousEventComplete = false;
            $(".LoaderImage").css("display", "block");

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: 'ajax/query.php',
                data: "from=" + counter,

                success: function (html) {
                    $("#comments").append(html);
                    counter++;
                    isPreviousEventComplete = true;

                    if (html == '') isDataAvailable = false;

                    $(".LoaderImage").css("display", "none");
                },
                error: function (error) {
                    alert("error " + error);
                }
            });

        }
    }
});
```

Works like a charm. Thanks to [Hendry Tanaka](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4072763/hendry-tanaka) for pointing me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

Best solution would be to you limit combination in mysql query.

example

```
`SELECT * FROM comment ORDER BY time DESC LIMIT 0,10;  # Retrieve rows 1-10`
```

and subsequently you can try using

```
`SELECT * FROM comment ORDER BY time DESC LIMIT 10,10;  # Retrieve rows 11-20`
```

and so on, to retrieve 10 comments at a time every time you scroll.

Comment: Limiting the sql is easy, however I'm more referring to how to display the comments dynamically.
`function load(){var comments = document.getElementById("comments");
comments.innerHTML += "<?php $counter = 0; include 'comments.php'; ?>";
counter+=2;
            }`
is what I'm trying to use at the moment with:
`$query  = "SELECT * FROM comment ORDER BY time DESC LIMIT ".$counter.",".($counter+2);`
but I cannot set $counter within the <?php as a javascript variable. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Just load all of your data and hide the second data until the last one. Use jquery tricks like scrollTop() to detect scrolling and fadeIn() your div step by step if user scroll value has a same value with scrollTop() return value while user scrolling mouse.

Comment: If I had 100+ comments this wouldn't be the best method. But thanks for your advice.